# How do I sort my List<string[]> by DateTime?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, datetime, format

I don't get how I'm supposed to sort this list by date.. I only know how to sort when its DateTime format or an int. Maybe I'm doing something completly wrong since I'm new.

Do I need to do a second list/array with DateTime? I've tried but I couldn't figure out how to connect it. And when I tried doing a bubble sort it didn't work because of the lists format

```
List<string[]> msgBoard = new List<string[]>();
string[] info = new string[3];   
Console.WriteLine("\tTitle: ");                        
string title = Console.ReadLine();                       
info[0] = title;                        
Console.WriteLine("\tMessage: ");                        
string msg = Console.ReadLine();                        
info[1] = msg;
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); 
info[2] = date;                        
msgBoard.Add(info);
```

All I want to do is to sort the list by using the dates I'll save.

Comment: Which list? What is `loggBok`? `logg` is coming from where? `msgBoard` is unused. Btw, use a DateTime object if you want to order by DateTime, not a string.

Comment: title and msg also string with yyyy/MM/dd format?

Comment: Sry Jimi, I fixed it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should sort convert that `string[]` into an object.  Consider this code:

```
private class Entry {
 public string Message { get; set;}
 public string Title { get; set;}
 public DateTime Date { get; set;}
}

...
//your code converted to use this `Entry` object rather than a `string[]`

List<Entry> msgBoard = new List<Entry>();

Entry info = new Entry();    

Console.WriteLine("\tTitle: ");    
string title = Console.ReadLine();    
info.Title = title;    

Console.WriteLine("\tMessage: ");    
string msg = Console.ReadLine();    
info.Message = msg;    

string date = DateTime.Now;    
info.Date = date;    

loggBok.Add(logg);
loggBok.Sort(new Comparison<Entry>((Entry x, Entry y) => x.Date.CompareTo(y.Date)));
```

BUT **if you must** sort your list and it **has to be an array of strings**, you would do it like this (assuming element[2] of each of your strings it the date in yyyy/MM/dd format):

```
loggBox.Sort(new Comparison<string[]>((string[] x, string[] y)=>
   DateTime.ParseExact(x[2], "yyyy/MM/dd").CompareTo(
   DateTime.ParseExact(y[2], "yyyy/MM/dd"))));
```

Comment: Second part is sooooo complicated: `loggBox = loggBox.OrderBy(x => x[2]).ToList()`

Comment: That looks so much cleaner.

Comment: I can't actually use a class like that yet in my course (for some reason). I used the solution Alexei wrote but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: *In this instance* for dates in the format yyyy/MM/dd lexical order is the same as chronological order, so you can treat them as strings for sorting instead of converting back to `DateTime`.